# Grouping Meshes & adding materials to multiple meshes at one time

Tags: materials, texture-painting, groups

[image]*Main goal: Group individual meshes and apply specific materials to each group*

I imported an obj that was supplied to me by a client. It is protein structure that is comprised of small spheres. It has 4 separate sections which is indicated by different colors but each sphere is its own mesh layer.

I want to group each section but keep the individual spheres and then color each group accordingly. Basically I want to control the appearance but it is unrealistic to try to do each sphere individually as there is over 10,000.

I am brand new to Blender but used Maya quite a bit about 10 years ago. I apologize if this is a rudimentary question but my basic searches have been unsuccessful. Thank you!

Comment: Can you include some screen shots explaining the mesh and what you are trying to attain as a result? I am not sure if you are just needing to set up vertex groups or if you can just set up particular materials per object and rejoin the sections....

Comment: Thanks Craig. I attached a screen shot. I would like to group the spheres according to the colors but right now they are all individual spheres. I want to change the appearance of each section with textures and colors.

Comment: Does each section not already have a shared material?  If you go to the materials tab and look at the name for a few green spheres for example is it the same?

Comment: Yes, look at the material shader properties and see if you have a single material for the green color, and if it is 1000 users of that material or if you have 1000 different green materials....